# Displaying text from 2 other TextViews gives a surprising output

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 2 `TextViews`. 1 get's the score from the first half (`ScoreHelft`) and the second TextView from the second half (`ScoreEind`).

```
ScoreHelft.setText(String.valueOf(counterThuis) + " - " + String.valueOf(counterUit));
```

This gives a result as expected, for example: 0 - 0

I now have 2 TextViews with 2 scores, for example: 0 - 0 and 1 - 1. This part works.

However, when I want to put those 2 together into an other `TextView`, which I want to combine the 2 results into a `TextView` that shows:

> 0-0 (1-1)

I used this code:

```
results.setText(ScoreHelft + " (" + ScoreEind + ")");
```

Now this doesn't work as I expected. If I print the output it gives me what's quoted below, plus pretty much the same kind of text, but ending on `app:id/ScoreHelft` and `app:id/ScoreEind`. But it only prints those extra things on the screen, not in the Monitor for some reason.

> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{b91f78 V.ED..... ......ID 32,713-147,751 #7f0d0085 app:id/results

.

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong to get this output.

Comment: `results.setText(ScoreHelft.getText().toString() + " (" + ScoreEind.getText().toString() + ")");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass view references to [`setText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) function

`setText(ScoreHelft + " (" + ScoreEind + ")"`

where `ScoreHelft` and `ScoreEind` are `TextView` references so you need to fetch the text using `yourTextView.getText().toString()` function

```
results.setText(ScoreHelft.getText().toString() + " (" + ScoreEind.getText().toString() + ")");
```

Comment: That fixed it! That output threw me off. Thnx for the quick response :)

Comment: I will, but you responded so fast that I need to wait a couple of minutes ;)

Comment: i am glad that i could help , happy coding :)